# Retrieving Particular column from db into Spinner

Tags: android, database, sqlite

[My SqliteDB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QTIv1.jpg)

In the above link am having my db screenshot

How to load that fiGoods column values into Spinner. Since am new to android kindly help me with full code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write Query to get fiGoods

```
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor res = db.rawQuery("select fiGoods from fiGoodsDetail", null);
    String[] figoodslist;
    res.moveToFirst();
    int i=0;
    while(!res.isAfterLast())
    {
        figoodslist[i] = res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("fiGoods"));
        i++;
    }
```

Get fiGoods value in String array.Then you have to bind array to spinner like this...

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adaper = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, YOUR_STRING_ARRAY);
spinner.setAdapter(adaper);
```

Comment: how to get fiGoods values into array is my main doubt

Comment: when I use this . figoodslist[i] = re.getString("figoods");  throwing error that The method getString(int) in the type Cursor is not applicable for the arguments (String)

Comment: If I updated the above code int the line                                            figoodslist[i] = res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("fiGoods"));         it throwing the error "The local variable figoodslist may not have been initialized"

Answer (score 0):

To link sqlite values to an adapter, use the handy [CursorAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html) class.